# ASP.NET/C# web app cannot 'find' Azure SQL server database

Tags: iis, azure, sql, asp.net

I've done similar web apps in the past and I've never had an issue with the SQL connection string.

I've tried several variations and still I get the following error:

> iisexpress.exe Error: 0 : Authentication to host
>   'coltsagdeep.database.windows.net' for user
>   'groupadminlogin@coltsagdeep' using method 'mysql_native_password'
>   failed with message: The server name you tried cannot be found. Please
>   use the correct name and retry. Please check your server name
>   coltsagdeep.

Could this be a problem with iisexpress? The web also has problems because I haven't installed a certificate, so my browser doesn't trust it initially, could this be the problem. I know I have the server and browser information correct, so I'm thinking its an issue with either the MySQL.Data library, or iisexpress, or something else. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It won't be IIS it's more likely your local ODBC/.NET MySQL driver.

Try `groupadminlogin@coltsagdeep.database.windows.net`, `groupadminlogin@localhost`, or just `groupadminlogin`.